# C++: Low level file operations

Tags: c++, file-io

I try to understand file operations in C.

My goal is to write some values into a binary file, called file1.dbs, then read those values and write them properly into a text file, called file2.txt.

At the bellow piece of code I am creating a struct product1. Then the binary file, **fn1**, and write the struct product p1 inside of it.

Finally I created the file2.txt (FILE ***f**) with permission to write, read the values of the fn1 file, stored them in a new struct p2, and tried to write those values into the f stream through fprintf().

I compiled the program, on Windows 10, and here is the output when I ran it:

**OUTPUT on file2.txt**
Product name:(Here was a weird symbol that cannot even copied)

Supplier:

Price:5110744

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "io.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "fcntl.h"
#define file1 "file1.dbs"
#define file2 "file2.txt"


struct product{
    char name[70];
    char supplier[70];
    int price;
};

FILE *f;
int fn1;

int main(){
    fn1=_open(file1, _O_CREAT|_O_RDWR);
    if(fn1==-1){
        printf("file1.dbs could not be created\n");
    }else{
        printf("file1.dbs created succesfully\n");
    }

    product p1;
    strcpy(p1.name, "Gameboy");
    strcpy(p1.supplier, "Gamestore");
    p1.price=15;
    write(fn1, &p1, sizeof product);
    product p2;
    f=fopen(file2, "w");
    read(fn1, &p2, sizeof product);
    fprintf(f,"Profuct name:%s\nSupplier:%s\nPrice:%d", p2.name, p2.supplier, p2.price);
    close(fn1);
    fclose(f);
    printf("Done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? 
I believe in that particular example I do not need to use lseek, to reposition the offset of the file1.dbs file, because I wrote only one struct. Appreciate your help!

Comment: ' I do not need to use lseek, to reposition the offset of the file1.dbs file, because I wrote only one struct' - think again.....

Comment: Uhm... by default the offset of the file is not 0? So if I am going to read a "sizeof product" that is going to be the first struct I passed?

Comment: `#include <iostream>` shows this is C++, not C. They are not the same languages. If you want to use C, compile with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler. Otherwise, use C++ features.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks Martin!

Comment: The "product p1" declaration is C++ as well. It should be "struct product p1" in C.

Comment: You are performing *serialization*.  Search the internet for "C++ serialization" for more information, especially about the items you can't write to files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 read(fn1, &p2, sizeof product);
       ^
```

Here you are using the same file descriptor opened in read/write mode. But after the `write` the current offset will be after the struct, you should reposition it to the beginning through `lseek`.

Actually you have like

```
file.dbs 
         ^
write(...)
file.dbs struct_data
                    ^
read(...)
file.dbs struct_data????????
                            ^
```